# How to know if it is EOF without stdio.h?

Tags: c, io

### Problem

I tried to write a code which reads from file to stdout without `stdio.h`.
The problem is that the file does not stop at EOF.

Here is the code:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define BUFF_SIZE 1024
#define EOF ???
int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
  int file_desc = open(argv[1], O_RDWR);
  char buff[BUFF_SIZE];
  read(file_desc, buff, BUFF_SIZE);
  int i = 0;
  while ( buff[i] != EOF){
    write(1, &buff[i], 1);
    i++;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

### Code Explanation

1. includes above the code imports: open(), read() and write()
   functions which are all linux syscalls.
2. for now buffer size is 1024.
3. **EOF** is not known.

   - tried (-1) as it's defined in stdio.h
   - tried 0x03 and 0x04 hex codes for CTRL+D and CTRL+C.
   - tried 0x1a hex code for CTRL+Z.
4. file_desc is an integer type stores a file descriptor with filename argv[1].
5. reading file_desc data into buffer.
6. a loop to write from buffer to STDIN which is 1 until buffer is EOF.

### What do I want?

Need an approach to break the loop `if buff[i] == EOF`.

Comment: The `read` function does not store EOF in `buff`. Instead it returns how many characters were successfully read, or an error code. Check documentation for `read`.

Comment: Don't even redefine standard macros. If you *need* the macro the include the header file it's defined in. But as told by @M.M you don't need it here. Furthermore, even if you used the standard C I/O functions, they would not put `EOF` *in* the data, but return it from the function. You really need to read some manual pages and tutorials.

Comment: When `char` is unsigned, the `while ( buff[i] != EOF)` is an infinite loop.

Comment: Check the return value of `read()`.

Comment: You should open the file with `O_RDONLY`, I think; you don't write to it.  You should check that the `open()` succeeded.  You should capture the number of bytes read — and check it.  You shouldn't write single bytes.  You need a loop in case the input is bigger than your buffer size — unless you want a single line of input at the terminal.  You have problems with EOF detection as others noted — you won't find EOF in the buffer (at least, not reliably — only by accident, and under modestly weird circumstances).

Comment: side note: EOF is NOT a valid `char` value. It's usually an `int` and it's value is implementation dependent. You can **never** check for EOF using `buff[i] != EOF `.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no character called "EOF". Some terminals have a character that they translate into an end-of-file indication, but you're not working with terminals here. The return value of `read` tells you how many characters you read.

Answer (score 0):

This code reads from a named file and writes to standard output without using `<stdio.h>` for those operations.  It uses `fprintf(stderr, …)` to report errors because writing the equivalent code to use plain `write()` is modestly frustrating — unless you use POSIX function [`dprintf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dprintf.html), but that's declared in `<stdio.h>`, even though it doesn't use file streams.

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define BUFF_SIZE 1024

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s file\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }
    int fd = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);
    if (fd < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: failed to open file '%s' for reading\n", argv[0], argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }
    char buff[BUFF_SIZE];
    int nbytes;

    while ((nbytes = read(fd, buff, BUFF_SIZE)) > 0)
        write(STDOUT_FILENO, buff, nbytes);

    close(fd);
    return 0;
}
```

The key point about detecting EOF is that [`read()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/read.html) returns 0 bytes read when it detects EOF, or `-1` on an error.  So, there is more work to do when the number of bytes returned is strictly positive.